# Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+ $ s.t $n$ has no square factors other than 1. Prove that for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n|x^2 \implies n|x$

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, divisibility, solution-verification

I tried to prove above theorem.
I used the Theorem:
Let p be a prime number. Then for any $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}; p|ab \implies p|a$ or $p|b$.
**Proof:**
Since $n|x^2$,  $x^2 = an$.
By prime factorization,
$n = p_1^{t_1}p_2^{t_2}...p_k^{t_k}$ ; $t_1,t_2,...,t_k$ are all odd integers.
$\therefore p_i | n$ for some i $\in \{1,2,...,i\}$
$\therefore p|x^2 \implies p|x$ (Theorem)

Then I can write $x^2=bp_i$ and $x = cp_i$.
$\therefore c^2p_i^2 = bp_i$
$c^2p_i = b$
$\therefore c|b$.

Futher by using $x^2 = an$ and $x^2=bp_i$,
$p_i=\frac{an}{b}$
By substituting this to $x=cp_i$,
$x=\frac{c}{b}.an$
Since $c|b$,
$x=kan$
$\therefore n|x$.(Proved)

Is this proof correct? Is there any better approach or other method?

Comment: It's not correct, since you are not using that $n$ has no square factors besides $1$. In fact this means, that all the $t_i =1$ for all $i \in {1,....,k}$. For example $n=2^3*3$ and $x=12$ would be a counterexample for the above.

Comment: @Nimantha In your proof, it seems you misunderstood the question, JVHD2334's comment states. Another counter-example is if $n = 8 = 2^3$, $x = 4$, so $n \mid x^2 = 16$, but $8 \not\mid 4$. When it says "$n$ has no square factors", this means that $n$ is a [square-free integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer), i.e., all of its prime factors are to a power of $1$ only. You seem to have thought it meant the powers must be odd integers. Note my proposed duplicate shows that actually *only* square-free integers satisfy what you're asked to prove.

Answer (score 1):

Define $p_{i}$ as prime factor of $x$ and $x=\prod p_{i}^{a_{i}}, a_{i}\geq 1$. Therefore $x^{2}=\prod p_{i}^{2a_{i}}$.

If $n|x^{2}$ then $n=\prod p_{i}^{b_{i}}, b_{i}\in\{0,1\}$ (remember that $n$ has no square factor?). Since $b_{i}\leq a_{i}$ , then $n|x$

Comment: Shouldn't it be $n=\prod p_{i}^{b_{i}}, b_{i}\in\{0,1\}$

Answer (score 1):

This theorem is true when n can be expressed as a product of distinct primes (every prime factor should be raised to the power of $1$)
$$ n|x^2 \implies n|x.x$$
By writing x in terms of the product of its prime factors (say $p_1, p_2,...,p_k$), we get
$$n|(p_1^{2a_1}p_2^{2a_2}...p_k^{2a_k})$$
$$\implies n=\frac{p_1^{2a_1}p_2^{2a_2}...p_k^{2a_k}}{a}, a \in \mathbb{Z}$$
Since n has no repeating prime factors, it should be expressible as follows.
$$n=\prod p_i^{b_i},$$ where $b_i$ can be either $0$ or $1$. For every value of $n$, it can be seen that $n|x$.